# All href attribute values has been overwritten in office apps

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

When i publish office 365 outlook add-in(with office.js) all href values has been overwritten to app source url + token data. but previously there was no such a issue. is there  any reason for that ?

Ex:-

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276814">Find more samples online...</a>
```

has been changed to following

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276814?et=&amp;_host_Info=Outlook|Web|16.00#&amp;_xdm_Info=-2c92131c_-49d09cf4_1447147594009|ocii7|https://outlook.office.com/owa/?realm=davtonenterprise.onmicrosoft.com#path=/mail">Find more samples online...</a>
```

and

```
 <a href="#" class="close-panel">close</a>
```

has changed to

```
<a href="https://localhost:44300/AppRead/Home/Home.html?et=&amp;_host_Info=Outlook|Web|16.00#?et=&amp;_host_Info=Outlook|Web|16.00#&amp;_xdm_Info=-2c92131c_-49d09cf4_1447147594009|ocii7|https://outlook.office.com/owa/?realm=davtonenterprise.onmicrosoft.com#path=/mail" class="close-panel">close</a>
```

Comment: I tried to repro your scenario but unfortunately I don't see the URL overridden. What I did is I create a sample app with Visual Studio template. Then I debug it on OWA. See screenshot. Can you explain a bit more on what you did, and what your repro environment is (which host application? which version? are you using the CDN for JS..., etc)? Thanks,
Sky
[Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2G8dz.jpg)

Comment: Yea, I don't understand the report either - where do you have these hrefs in your add-in? At what point do you see them overwritten?

Comment: [@Michael](http://stackoverflow.com/users/678505/michael-zlatkovsky), I also tried with same VS default office app  project by adding  additional two links as this  image.
[SCREENSHOT-Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/AHtq1w7.png)
probably it should be my machine issue. but i am getting same issue  for all browsers( chrome, FF, IE).I also tried by reinstalling browsers, cache clearing,
using different mail  account ,still no idea why it is happening .

i am using VS 2015/win8,Chrome  Version 46.0.2490.86 m (64-bit)

Comment: @Sky . it was working fine OWA before i test office store license token.i tested license validation using manifest file by appending token data to SourceLocation element as following

 Ex:

 `<SourceLocation DefaultValue="http://myApp/index.htm?et= PAByAD4APAB0A.........AcgA%2bAA%3d%3d" /> `